# How do I refactor OpenSSL pkcs5_keyivgen in ruby?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I have been using the following code in my app for the past year and have 200k record using this code:

```
options = { :algorithm => 'aes-256-cbc', :value => "changethis", :key => "secretkey" }
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(options[:algorithm])
cipher.send(:encrypt)    
cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(options[:key])
result = cipher.update(options[:value])
result << cipher.final
# => "x\xED\x14s\xFD\x0E\x97\xC5\x996[M\x1E\x94\xDEI"
```

I am required (by business) to refactor the `pkcs5_keyivgen` part, to do it correctly: For example,

```
options = { :algorithm => 'aes-256-cbc', :value => "changethis", :key => "secretkey" }
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(options[:algorithm])
cipher.send(:encrypt)
cipher.key = '' # ??? 1) How does pkcs5_keyivgen in above code generate key, or does it just use my options[:key]
cipher.iv = '' # ??? 2) How does pkcs5_keyivgen in above code generate iv
result = cipher.update(options[:value])
result << cipher.final
```

I have to figure out how `pkcs5_keyivgen` sets `key` and `iv`. ideas here? We are using ruby-1.9.3-p286 and encryptor-1.1.3

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349397/how-to-resolve-deprecation-warnings-for-opensslciphercipherencrypt) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311623/translating-ruby-encryption-code-to-java), but they haven't help me solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being proposed to be closed?  It is a programming question?  would you please give feedback why you downvote, so i can improve the question. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was trying to solve this problem, but I think there is no easy solution or i just can't see one). `Pkcs5_keyivgen()` is deprecated and implements non-standard pass key derivation for AES 256.

From this [docs](http://doc.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.9.3/method/OpenSSL=3a=3aCipher/i/pkcs5_keyivgen.html) and this [source code](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-pkcs5_keyivgen)

```
Pkcs5_keyivgen (pass, SALT = nil, num = 2048, digest = "MD5") -> nil
```

Generates some key and IV from salt and pass. No salt in your case. Generation method is defined in `v1.5 PKCS #5` (deprecated)

So you are looking for "Password Based Key Derivation Function". [PBKDF1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-does-pbkdf1-work)

`Pkcs5_keyivgen()` function calls `EVP_BytesToKey()` from Openssl and `EVP_BytesToKey()` generates key bytes for larger key size in a [non-standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624895/clarifying-the-evp-bytestokey-function-in-openssl)

So MD5 generates hash of size `EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE (16 + 20)` // 16 for MD5

But AES `key(32) + IV(16) sizes > EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE`, so AES 256 will need multiple hashes to generate random key and IV. Here is [source code](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/android-boinc/libssl/crypto/evp/evp_key.c) of algorithm in C

And here is nice [pseudo-code explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008253/c-sharp-version-of-openssl-evp-bytestokey-method) of the `EVP_BytesToKey()`

If you really want to re-implement PBKDF1 here is also [RTC2898 standard for PBKDF1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.1)
But i don't think that it is a good idea to implement crypto yourself

Comment: Amazing feedback. The true reason i am trying to reverse engineer this is because i need to use it in a Python program as well and sound like I may have to re-implement my ruby the standard way and then do it in python the standard way as well.

Comment: [OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.